# Android : Record audio app crash

Tags: java, android, audio

Everybody,

I'm trying to make a simple audio recording.

The audio is record perfectly when record button is clicked.

I try to record another audio and play it back. It crash when I try to play the 2nd audio.

Can you please help me on fixing this app so that I can record audio multiple time without crashing the app.

Here's the code.

```
  stop.setEnabled(false);
  play.setEnabled(false);
  outputFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/recording.3gp";;

  myAudioRecorder=new MediaRecorder();
  myAudioRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
  myAudioRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
  myAudioRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
  myAudioRecorder.setOutputFile(outputFile);

  record.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
           myAudioRecorder.prepare();
           myAudioRecorder.start();
        }


        catch (IllegalStateException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
        }

        catch (IOException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
        }

        record.setEnabled(false);
        stop.setEnabled(true);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Recording started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
  });

  stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
        myAudioRecorder.stop();
        myAudioRecorder.reset();

        record.setEnabled(true);
        stop.setEnabled(false);
        play.setEnabled(true);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Audio recorded successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
  });

 play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) throws IllegalArgumentException,SecurityException,IllegalStateException {
        MediaPlayer m = new MediaPlayer();

        try {
           m.setDataSource(outputFile);
        }

        catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
           m.prepare();
        }

        catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }

        m.start();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Playing audio", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
  });
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to enable record button when stop button is clicked. Write

```
record.setEnabled(true);
```

in the onClick() method implementation of stop button.

Another case is when stop button is clicked you are setting `myAudioRecorder = null`. If after this record button is clicked you will get a NullPointerException on this statement

```
myAudioRecorder.prepare() //exception
```

Solution will be to remove the statement of setting myAudioRecorder to null in onClick() implementation of stop.

Another problem comes because of this statement `myAudioRecorder.release()`. You can't get back the previous instance of `MediaRecorder` once you have released the resource. Either reinitialize `myAudioRecorder` each time you record or do not release the resource after stop has been clicked. To look at `MediaRecorder` lifecycle [see this.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html)

Here is a reference code you can look and understand. Please catch exceptions wherever required.

```
//package name
//imports
public class RecordPlayActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
// declare buttons here
private MediaRecorder myAudioRecorder;
private String recordOutputFile;
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(null);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_name);
    //find buttons view by Id here
    record.setOnClickListener(this);
    stop.setOnClickListener(this);
    play.setOnClickListener(this);
    recordOutputFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/recording.3gp";
    myAudioRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    myAudioRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    myAudioRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    myAudioRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
    myAudioRecorder.setOutputFile(recordOutputFile);
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(recordOutputFile);
    //Initial condition
    //stop.setEnabled(false);   //not required as stop can be made always enabled
    play.setEnabled(false);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view){
    switch(view.getId()){
        case R.id.idForRecord:
            myAudioRecorder.prepare();
            myAudioRecorder.start();
            //Recording started
            record.setEnabled(false);
            // don't make play enabled cause you dont want to play
            // and record at same time without stopping record.
            play.setEnabled(false); //required because play can get enabled from stop but it should not remain when recording
            break;
        case R.id.idForStop:
            //if clicked after record
            myAudioRecorder.stop();
            myAudioRecorder.reset();
            //if clicked after play
            if(mediaPlayer.isLooping()) {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
            }
            //recording stopped and saved;
            record.setEnabled(true);
            play.setEnabled(true);
            break;
        case R.id.idForPlay:
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            mediaPlayer.start();
            //playing
            record.setEnabled(false); // you dont wanna play and record at same time
            break;
        default:
    }
}
```

}`

Hope these all solves your problem.

Comment: The button is enable but it doesn't function. @GauravChauhan

Comment: @Mint are you getting any nullpointerexception or App crash when you click on record after stop?

Comment: The app crash even when I remove the null statement. @GauravChauhan

Comment: It work fine but when I try to record again the app crash.

Comment: @Mint It's because you are releasing the mediarecorder when stop is clicked. Editing the answer.

Comment: I delete the statement `myAudioRecorder.release();` and add `myAudoRecorder.reset();` to stop onclick implementation. It work and I can record another audio but when I try to play them, the app crash. Is there anything else should I add at the stop onclick implementation?

Comment: @Mint Please see [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) lifecycle of MediaPlayer and implement accordingly. You are messing up because you are not following the same.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't really understand the cycle. I'm kinda new and still trying to sort thing out. Anyway thanks a lot. What about setLooping? Will it make the app work? @GauravChauhan

Comment: @Mint I have provided a reference code you can look. Look for the comments for understanding.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll get back to you if I encountered any problem.

Comment: Btw to be more clear I am using the same stop button to stop both recording and playing. And accept the answer if your issue is solved.

Answer (score 0):

It's  crashing because  outputFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/recording.3gp" ;  directs to top directory od Android OS ...

If you  use  this path Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"sounds" "/recording.3gp" then your recording will be going into one level down directory "sounds" into directory sounds .

App will not crash if you recording is  in folder down from top level path ...